# Bitwarden docker with apache reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache2 server for my cloud and Collabora_online(with Apache reverse proxy) and now I've tried to install Bitwarden on my server(self-hosted) but there is one problem, in the Bitwarden docker is already Nginx as webserver and if I will start Bitwarden, Nginx failed to start on port 0.0.0.0:443, cause my Apache server already listing on this port. Is there a way to start Nginx with Apache and redirect from Apache to my Bitwarden-docker with Nginx?

My install way:

```
curl -Lso bitwarden.sh https://go.btwrdn.co/bw-sh && chmod +x bitwarden.sh
```

```
sudo ./bitwarden.sh install
```

source https://help.bitwarden.com/article/install-on-premise/#install-bitwarden

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using Apache as your "frontend" (reverse) proxy, just change the listening port of your nginx and tell apache to fetch content there. This is done by changing the `listen` parameter in your nginx config, for example to `8443`.

- Debian based: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
- Most others: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Then just add another `vhost` or path directive to your Apache (and SSL offload if you wish to do so).

Most people tend to SSL Offload on their frontend proxy and make direct http request to their backends, but this is up to you.